# When finding the prime factors of a number some numbers work but others dont

Tags: python, primes

When testing numbers some work for example 48, but others don't. I'm not sure what the best way to approach finding all the factors of a number.

## Prime Factorization

```
def find_primes(n): 
    factors = []
    i = 2
    if n == 0:
        return 0              
    if n == 1:
        return 1                
    if n >= 2:
        while n % i == 0:
            next_n = n / i
            factors.append(i)
            n = next_n 
            if n % i != 0:
                i += 1
                continue
            elif i == n:
                break
    if len(factors) == 0:
        return "{} is a prime number.\n".format(initial_n)
    else:
        return "The prime factors of {} are: {}\n".format(initial_n, factors)


n = int(input("Enter a number to find all the Prime Factors:"))
initial_n = n
print('\n')
print(find_primes(n))
```

I am expecting to get a list of all the factors of a number.

Comment: The while-loop is left (or never entered) if an i can't divide n at least once regardless if greater values for i could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function to calculate the prime factors below is much simpler than the one above. The rest is just sanity checking of user input.

```
###########################################################
#Main function to calculate prime factors
def find_prime_factors(n):
    factors = []
    p = 2
    while n > p ** 2:
        if n % p == 0:
            factors.append(p)
            n //= p
        else:
            p += 1
    factors.append(n)
    return factors
###########################################################

# Get User input
n = input('Enter a number to find all the Prime Factors: ') 

# Check if the entered value is a number
while not n.isnumeric():
    print('Entered number was not numeric.')
    n = input('Enter a NUMBER to find all the Prime Factors: ') 

# Check the entered value is greater than one (1)
# Prime Factor check happens on only positive numbers that are greater than one (1)

while int(n) < 2:
    print("Please enter a positive number that is greater than one (1).")
    n = input('Enter a NUMBER to find all the Prime Factors: ') 

#Python 3.7 string formating
print(f'The prime factor(s) of {n}: {find_prime_factors(int(n))} ')
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code and now it works for all natural numbers:

```
def find_primes(n): 
    factors = []
    i = 2
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    if n >= 2:
        while i * i <= n:
            while n % i == 0:
                factors.append(i)
                n = n // i
            i += 1
    if n > 1:
        factors.append(n)
    if len(factors) == 1:
        return "{} is a prime number.\n".format(initial_n)
    else:
        return "The prime factors of {} are: {}\n".format(initial_n, factors)


n = int(input("Enter a number to find all the Prime Factors:"))
initial_n = n
print('\n')
print(find_primes(n))
```

Comment: thanks it works but i have a couple questions. Why did you use "while i * I <= n" in the first while statement? Also what is the point of the final if statement, "if n > 1"

Comment: @parth if n is a prime number, it has at least one divisor not greater than sqrt(n), so "while i * i <= n" will find that; otherwise n will be never divided by anything and we will check this by "n > 1".

Comment: Actually, using "i * i <= n" makes the algorithm faster in comparison to use "i <= n". It makes an O(n) algorithm to an O(sqrt(n)) one.

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_primes(n):
    factors = []
    i = 2
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    while i <= n:
        if n % i == 0:
            factors.append(i)
            n /= i
        else:
            i += 1
    if len(factors) == 0:
        return "{} is a prime number.\n".format(initial_n)
    else:
        return "The prime factors of {} are: {}\n".format(initial_n, factors)


n = int(input("Enter a number to find all the Prime Factors:"))
initial_n = n
print('\n')
print(find_primes(n))
```